# Nginx sites-available configuration

Tags: nginx

So, I emigrate from Apache to Nginx, and it is a terrible experience for me.

Right now I need your help with understanding of Nginx file of configuration:

```
server { 
            ....

            location / {

                    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php$is_args$args;
            }

            location ~ "^/([-0-9a-zA-Z_\s]+)$" {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /user/user?username=$1;
            }
            location ~ "^/trends/([.*]+)$" {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /trends/trend?name=$1;
            }
    
    }
```

When I type to the URL bar site https://example.com/someuser ,
it successfully redirect me (show to me the folder) to the folder example.com/user/user?username=someuser .
But when I trying to access to https://example.com/trends/sometrend
Nginx load me the page from the fist block.
Why it do this?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you expect `([.*]+)` to match? Did you mean `(.+)`?

Comment: All Unicode UTF-8 symbols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, for my late reply, but I suppose that it will be helpful for others, who will face with similar problem:

```
server {
...
        # enable utf8
        charset UTF-8;
        # pretty urls
        # user folder
        location ~ "^/([-0-9a-zA-Z_\s]+)$" {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /user/user?username=$1;
        }
        # trends
        location ~ "^/trends/([\x00-\xff]+)$" {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /trnds/trend?name=$1;
        }
...
}
```

Let me explain it in details.

1. \x00-\xff - it allow all symbols in Unicode format, don't forget to enable UTF-8 with charset UTF-8; in the server block.
2. /trnds/ - on official documentation to Nginx (cant find it now to post the link) they have a little explain that this folder shouldn't exist in the server if we have the same address in the URL bar.

So, I change try_files from /trends/ to /trnds/ and do refactor of folder on my server and everything work like a charm!